# pgbackups on Heroku not found

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have been using pgbackups to capture databases and load them locally but since yesterday, I am getting this message when provisioning the add on for new apps.

```
!    Add-on plan not found.
```

Has pgbackups been disabled for new instances? It still works on apps it was previously integrated with. If it has been deprecated, what is the recommended replacement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heroku have recently made changes. "*PG Backups as an add-on has been deprecated.*" For new commands, see here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mapping-pgbackups-commands

Old command:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --app sushi
```

New Command

```
heroku pg:backups capture --app sushi
```

Comment: I am getting the issue when I try to add the add on to a new app via:  heroku addons:add pgbackups

Comment: ja, I'm guessing it's not called "pgbackups" anymore - have you tried just "pg" like "pg:backups capture"

Comment: It looks like an addon is not required anymore. The commands just work out of the box. Thanks for the link with the updated commands.

Answer (score 2):

So I missed this little disclaimer here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

```
PG Backups as an add-on has been deprecated. The commands exist as part of the Heroku Postgres namespace in the CLI. The new functionality is live and available for use. We also have a mapping guide to show you how the old commands transfer to the new ones.
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to response from jcuenod above the same would apply for `heroku pg:backups:restore`. The new command will be `heroku pg:backups restore`. [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import-to-heroku-postgres) is inconsistent and should be updated.