# Heroku PGBackups - cannot see daily backups when running "heroku pg:backups"

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

This question was asked on 3/15/2015.

I read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups and learnt how to capture backups or schedule daily backup.

I used "heroku pg:backups schedule --at='02:00 EDT' DATABASE_URL --app MYAPPNAME" to set a daily backup of my app. However, two days later I could not find any daily backups.

To be more specific, when I used "heroku pg:backups" (devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#checking-backup-status), I saw "=== Backups ..." (backups I manually made would list there), but I did not see "=== Schedule DATABASE_URL: daily".

Heroku Toolbelt had the newest version.

I had heroku-postgresql as an add-on.

I did not have "PG Backups as an add-on", since it was deprecated (devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/623).

I am wondering if that is because my app is a personal app and it does not have the support of daily support, but I cannot find related information. **This was answered by jcuenod.**

**Now my question is I cannot see daily backups when I run "heroku pg:backups".**

Thanks

---

"heroku addons" gave me:

```
=== myapp Configured Add-ons 
heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA
```

"heroku pg:backups schedules" gave me:

```
=== Backup Schedules
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL: daily at 2:00 (America/New_York)
```

"heroku pg:backups" gave me:

```
=== Backups
ID    Backup Time                Status                              Size    Database
----  -------------------------  ----------------------------------  ------  --------
b003  2015-03-15 17:53:51 +0000  Finished 2015-03-15 17:54:11 +0000  75.9kB  AQUA
b002  2015-03-14 16:44:02 +0000  Finished 2015-03-14 16:44:15 +0000  75.8kB  AQUA
b001  2015-03-13 20:26:33 +0000  Finished 2015-03-13 20:26:39 +0000  75.2kB  AQUA

=== Restores
```

b001, b002 and b003 are all backups I manually made.

---

Heroku updated their tutorial (h_t_t_ps://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups) on 3/18/2015.

---

Heroku updated their tutorial (h_t_t_ps://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups) on 3/19/2015, again.

Comment: Also, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053867/pgbackups-on-heroku-not-found/29053924#29053924

Comment: What do you get with `heroku pg:backups schedules`?

Comment: And you're sure that `heroku pg:backups` is only listing backups you manually initiated?

Comment: I take it this is resolved with their updates?

Comment: what was the solution here? i am having the same problem. Is database level "Hobby Basic" does not have daily backups? i can do manual backups by the automatic daily ones are not firing at the time that i specified.

Comment: @DavidDehghan I do have daily backups on free apps. Here is some screenshots when I run "heroku pg:backups --app myappname" and "heroku pg:backups schedules --app myappname": h_t_t_p://1drv.ms/1F875nR

Comment: I only get entries like this for "heroku pg:backups":

"a014  2015-04-20 12:06:47 +0000  Finished 2015-04-20 12:06:52 +0000  1.96MB  COBALT",  which all start with "a". I will have to ask heroku support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans I see

> All tiers share the following features:
>
> ...
>
> - Daily logical database backups with PG Backups (optional but free)

The syntax you are using looks right.

Also, when I run `heroku addons`, I get

```
=== myapp Configured Add-ons
heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev  HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD
pgbackups:plus
```

What is the output of `heroku pg:backups schedules`?